The subreport 'Subreport1' could not be found at the specified location
Tengo que modificar un reporte que estaba funcionando, para ello instalé RDLC en visual studio 2019. Cuando quiero editar el reporte, me pide actualizar a una versión más reciente (la que tenía era 2010), se actualiza a 2016. Pude editar el reporte y el subreporte, pero cuando ejecuto me dá este error:
The subreport 'Subreport1' could not be found at the specified location
Verifiqué la ubicación del subreporte y el nombre, todo existe ( de hecho antes de migrar o cargaba bien, y lo hace también si deshago los cambios). También validé los parámetros (que de hecho no modifiqué) y tiene todos los que necesita.
¿Se les ocurre cuál puede ser el problema?
Gracias!
